# winapi - SetLayeredWindowAttributes with LWA_COLORKEY only sets pixels to either fully opaque or fully transparent?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

The border of my frame is white (0xfffffffe). The interior of my frame is black (0xff000000).
I want to make the border translucent (alpha value of 100), and the interior opaque. Obviously, I've used `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` to do this, but it's not working.

This variation: `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(RGB(0xxff, 0xff, 0xfe), 100, LWA_COLORKEY)` sets the border to alpha of 100, but the interior as completely transparent.

This variation: `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(RGB(0xxff, 0xff, 0xfe), 100, LWA_COLORKEY | LWA_ALPHA)` sets the interior to an alpha of 100, but sets the border as completely transparet.

How can I make the interior opaque and the border transparent? I can't use multiple top-level windows to achieve the affect in this situation.

Comment: You'll need a sandwich of *two* windows to get this effect.  It's clear from the comments on my deleted answer that you don't want to do that.  That's fine, nobody is forcing you to do this.

Comment: It's an option I just wondered if there was anything easier I could do. Cheers:)

Comment: @Hand Passant your method was better in the end. I ended up creating a structure of 3 windows, all moving and sizing in-sync to create the overall affect of my specific frame

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`, use [`UpdateLayeredWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can pre-render your entire frame including any transparency onto a 32-bit bitmap, select it into a DC and pass this to `UpdateLayeredWindow`.

Comment: Ok cool. Will this work if the frame has child controls aswell?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to use `UpdateLayeredWindow`?