# Transparent SDL2 Game (WIN32 Colorkeying not working correctly)

Tags: c++, sdl, transparency, transparent

I have a problem with my SDL2 Game. I want to make it transparent but it isn't working and I don't know why. I already tested it with SDL(1) and there it worked perfectly with surfaces. 
But now when I use textures with `SDL_Render` functions it doesn't work anymore.
First I get the `HWND` and then I call `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` as shown below but ONLY the LWA_ALPHA flag works in this case but when I change it to LWA_COLORKEY nothing happens to the window. That's quite strange because `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` still returns 1 even if you don't see the colorkeying.

Maybe some of you can help me to fix this.
Thank you in advance! Here my code and some screenshots:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_syswm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

bool init();
bool loadTexture();
void quit();

SDL_Window* gWindow = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* gRenderer = NULL;
SDL_Texture* gTexture = NULL;

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {
    if (!init()) {
        printf("Initialization failed!\n");
        quit();
        return 0;
    }

    SDL_SysWMinfo SysInfo;
    SDL_VERSION(&SysInfo.version);

    if (SDL_GetWindowWMInfo(gWindow, &SysInfo) <= 0) {
        printf("%s : %d\n", SDL_GetError(), SysInfo.info.win.window);
        quit();
        return 0;
    }

    HWND hWnd = SysInfo.info.win.window;

    // Handles the transparency of the window !!!
    // LWA_ALPHA works fine but LWA_COLORKEY doesn't work even the function returns 1.
    SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
    printf("success?: %i\n", SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(255, 0, 255), 100,         LWA_COLORKEY));

    //Load Texture
    if (!loadTexture()) {
        printf("Texture couldn't be loaded %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        quit();
        return 0;
    }

    bool run = true;
    SDL_Event e;

    while (run) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
            run = false;
        }

        SDL_RenderClear(gRenderer);
        SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, gTexture, NULL, NULL);
        SDL_RenderPresent(gRenderer);
    }

    return 0;
}

bool init() {
    if (SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) return false;

    gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Transparency test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,     SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (gWindow == NULL) return false;

    gRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(gWindow, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (gRenderer == NULL) return false;

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);

    return true;
}

void quit() {
    SDL_DestroyTexture(gTexture);
    gTexture = NULL;

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(gRenderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    gWindow = NULL;
    gRenderer = NULL;

    SDL_Quit();
}

bool loadTexture() {
    SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_LoadBMP("texture.bmp");
    if (surface == NULL) return false;

    gTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, surface);
    if (gTexture == NULL) return false;

    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    return true;
}
```

`SetLayeredWindowAttributes` with `LWA_ALPHA` and 100 for alpha,
Console outpout: `success?: 1` [With alpha screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43573535/first.png)

`SetLayeredWindowAttributes` with `LWA_COLORKEY`,
Console outpout: `success?: 1` [With colorkey screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43573535/second.png)
(The texture's background color is `RGB(255, 0, 255)` so it should work but it doesn't.)

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252864/winapi-setlayeredwindowattributes-with-lwa-colorkey-only-sets-pixels-to-either

Comment: @young No. This is something completely different.

Comment: Were you ever able to get a transparent window working? I have been googling for days now trying to figure out a way to do it with no luck.

Comment: @yaegerbomb I get a working one in SLD 1 but in SLD 2 I can't get it to work either because SLD2 is rendering with the gpu so it doesn#t work. I stopped working on my project maybe  I continue in the next months...

Comment: I've also googled around and experimented a few hours without success. If anyone finds a solution, please share it.

Answer (score 0):

You may be working the way you are for a reason and if so that is fine but if not, why don't you just set the colour key on the surface before texture creation:

```
bool loadTexture() {
    SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_LoadBMP("texture.bmp");
    if (surface == NULL) return false;

    // Map the colour key
    Uint32 colorkey = SDL_MapRGB(surface->format, 0xFF, 0x00, 0xFF);
    // Set all pixels of colour R(255), G(0), B(255) to be transparent
    SDL_SetColorKey(surface, SDL_SRCCOLORKEY, colourkey);

    gTexture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(gRenderer, surface);
    if (gTexture == NULL) return false;

    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what I wanted. Here is a screenshot so you can see how it should look like: [Screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43573535/third.png)
I made this using `SDL_BlitSurface`and `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface` but I want to use `SDL_Renderer`and textures but as described above only the `LWA_ALPHA`works and the `LWA_COLORKEY`doesn't make anything.

Comment: Sorry I see what you are trying to achieve now. I will do some testing on my system.